# how can I upload an image in Jhipster?

Tags: angular, spring, server, upload, jhipster

I faced a problem when i tried to **upload an image** in **Jhipster6** using spring and angular. My problem is that i can't find  Jhipster upload's files and server that it uses.

Answer (score 1):

JHipster stores files into the database when you add blob fields to entities, https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields#blob-declaration

If this does not fit your requirements, you can code it manually, JHipster apps are only Spring Boot apps.

Comment: I can not store the images with the type string? Is it an obligation to store them into blob ?

Comment: Encoding binary data in a string would require to encode data in base64.

Comment: and when you upload files where do you find them ? in which file?

Comment: I already  answered this: in a blob column of your table which is mapped to a field of your entity. Did you try to generate it? Are you a beginner in java and Spring boot?

Comment: No problem but I suggest that you start by learning about the technology stack of JHipster: Spring Boot, Hibernate and Angular otherwise you'll have much trouble understanding the code that JHipster generates.